# How to programmatically render a node's teaser using the theme layer?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

How do I programmatically render a node's teaser using the theme layer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7) is the standard function for rendering nodes, e.g.

```
$node = node_load(1);
$view = node_view($node, 'teaser');
$rendered = drupal_render($view);
```

There is a `node` theme defined by the node module (in [`node_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_theme/7)) but I've never actually seen it used.

Comment: Isn't node_theme() what lets the theme system use a .tpl.php file for the element and also allow preprocess functions?

Comment: Yeah I'm concerned about bypassing the theme layer.  If I did that, then other modules wanting to chip in would not be able to.  At least, I think that's correct?

Comment: Upon analyzing http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7 if you view the implementation code, where it says `$build += array(`, it does have a `#theme` attribute in there which I'm guessing tells Drupal to use the theme system.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm just now starting to 'get' the Drupal API :)

Comment: @MPD Yeah I didn't explain that very well, I just meant I'd never seen a call like `theme('node', ...` before. In fact that wouldn't even work because it defines itself as having a `render element` instead of `variables`.

Comment: @Lester Spot on, there are 2 ways to call theme functions, the 'normal' way (`theme('theme_name', $args)` and by using so called `render element`s. The [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) docs explain it pretty well, it's not 100% intuitive but once you know, it's really useful. Using `node_view()` will never bypass the theme layer so you should be fine :)

Comment: I use the exact code with a different nid in a custom module. But does render the node but i does not pick the correct template file. I tried with a template file in my theme which does not work and i also tried with a template in my module which also does not work.