# Theming output of node_view

Tags: 7, theming

I'm printing the output as described in here: [How to programmatically render a node's teaser using the theme layer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53008/how-to-programmatically-render-a-nodes-teaser-using-the-theme-layer) in block using PHP filter.

Also I've a theme implementation file named: `views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php` in the custom Mobile theme directory with this content:

```
<?php

?>
<?php /*print $output;*/ ?>
```

This is hiding all image field output but not the output of drupal_render($view).

How to hide the images in this redered output as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `drupal_render($view)` inspect the $view array. (Use [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel)'s [dmp](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) or print_r to inspect the array.)

Find out what part of the array contains information about your images, and then unset this before calling drupal_render.

E.g.

```
unset($views['my-image-field']);
print drupal_render($view);
```